# Définition de bruit de couloir

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Je voudrais savoir la définition de :

> bruit de couloir

J'ai entendu cette expression dans une chanson française.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bruit de couloir

équivaut à:

> [radio-trottoir](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/radio-trottoir/66148)

et signifie simplement *rumeurs*.

Answer (score 1):

Une simple recherche sur Google [indique](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/6880/bruits-de-couloirs/) :

> Bruits de couloir
>   Signifie: **Rumeurs**

Answer (score 1):

Quelques traductions possibles de "bruit de couloir":

- something heard through the grapevine
- rumor
- hearsay
- scuttlebutt

Answer (score 1):

Il y a toute une variation sur le même thème des rumeurs, avec un niveau de qualité variable:

- bruit de couloir : rumeur banale
- bruit de *chiottes* (assez vulgaire, et colportant des informations négatives)
- radio-trottoir : rumeur banale
- radio-moquette : rumeur provenant des *hautes sphères*
- radio-XXX : ou XXX est une organisation, une équipe, ...
- le téléphone arabe: rumeur quelconque : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone_arabe